# Notification on slack username change

Tags: slack-api, slack

Am the admin for a slack team.

Is there a way for me (the admin) to get a notification whenever a user changes his username on slack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible using [events](https://api.slack.com/events).

You can subscribe to events and use either the [RTM API](https://api.slack.com/rtm) or the [Event API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) to make your bot listen to those events and react accordingly. I personally would recommend using the Event API, since it is much easier to implement.

The event `user_change` will be triggered each time a user makes changes to his/her profile. Your bot can then use the API method [users.profile.set](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set) to reset unwanted changes (this API method works on paid teams only).